# Mailboxes in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap

Is it possible to render & place public items such as mailboxes and fire hydrants in OpenStreetMap?

Comment: what do you mean by 'render & place'? there are values for mailboxes (and also benches and all sorts of public items) in the 'amenity' tag, e.g. 'amenity=post_box' (for the ones you want to send) or 'amenity=letter_box' (for the ones you get). you find hydrants in the 'emergency' tag. just google 'osm tag <whatever>' and you will find the tag key/value you want, if it exist. chances are there is a tag key/value for everything you can imagine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely. Here is the OSM wiki page on how to map fire hydrants. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:emergency=fire_hydrant

Here are the general guidelines on contributing map data: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Contribute_map_data